# /n in the Array From XML Parsing

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, xml-parsing

I am using NSXMLParser to parse a remote XML file to display information in my application.

I am storing the strings in an NSMutableArray. The information is provided in 4 tags which repeat themselves with more information.

Now, I am getting objects at indices in the form like " /n" "  ". "realdata", "/n", "realdata"

I have tried using the Stringsbyreplacingoccurencesofstring function but that just seems to remove the /n and return an empty index.

Please help.

The code:

```
    - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{

    currentElement = elementName ;


}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{

    string1 = string;
    string1 = [string1 stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@" \n\t"]];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{

    if([currentElement isEqualToString:@"CourseID"])
    {

        [CourseID addObject:string1];
    }

    if([currentElement isEqualToString:@"CourseName"])
    {
        [CourseName addObject:string1];

    }
    if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"CourseDescription"])
    {
        [CourseDescription addObject:string1];
    }
    if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"DescriptionType"])
    {
        [DescriptionType addObject:string1];

    }

}



- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser{

    NSLog(@"Course Name: %@",CourseName);
    NSLog(@"CourseID: %@",CourseID);
    NSLog(@"CourseDescription: %@",CourseDescription);
    NSLog(@"DescriptionType: %@",DescriptionType);


}
```

Output:

```
    2012-05-15 04:03:09.011 DispatchTestPrep[2290:f803] Course Name: (
    "Weather Theory",
    Turbulence,
    "Non-Graphic Weather",
    "Graphic Weather",
    Airport
)
2012-05-15 04:03:09.012 DispatchTestPrep[2290:f803] CourseID: (
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4,
    5
)
2012-05-15 04:03:09.012 DispatchTestPrep[2290:f803] CourseDescription: (
    "Aviation Weather Theory",
    Turbulence,
    "Non-Graphic Weather",
    "Graphic Weather",
    Airport
)
2012-05-15 04:03:09.012 DispatchTestPrep[2290:f803] DescriptionType: (
    Text,
    "",
    Text,
    "",
    Text,
    "",
    Text,
    "",
    Text,
    "",
    ""
)
```

As you can see the last "DescriptionType" array is showing those empty objects at index.

The XML File that's being parsed is:

```
<NewDataSet><Table><CourseID>1</CourseID><CourseName>Weather Theory</CourseName><CourseDescription>Aviation Weather Theory</CourseDescription><DescriptionType>Text</DescriptionType></Table><Table><CourseID>2</CourseID><CourseName>Turbulence</CourseName><CourseDescription>Turbulence</CourseDescription><DescriptionType>Text</DescriptionType></Table><Table><CourseID>3</CourseID><CourseName>Non-Graphic Weather</CourseName><CourseDescription>Non-Graphic Weather</CourseDescription><DescriptionType>Text</DescriptionType></Table><Table><CourseID>4</CourseID><CourseName>Graphic Weather</CourseName><CourseDescription>Graphic Weather</CourseDescription><DescriptionType>Text</DescriptionType></Table><Table><CourseID>5</CourseID><CourseName>Airspace & Airport</CourseName><CourseDescription>Airspace & Airport</CourseDescription><DescriptionType>Text</DescriptionType></Table></NewDataSet>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string { 
string =[string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\t" withString:@""];
string =[string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
if(!currentElement) 
    currentElement = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:string];
else
    [currentElement appendString:string];
```

}

Comment: appendString is not available for NSString data type.

Comment: change Data Type of  currentElement, NSString to NSMutableString